# Synonyme search Solr

Tags: solr

Using Solr 5_2_x

I would like to match honda to any civic or accord, toyota to any tercel or corola and so on. Also civic, accord, tercel and corola should individually match.

Is this consisered a synonyme search?

Answer (score 2):

it can be done with plain synonyms yes. Has some drawback though:

1. you have to compile the quite large synonym file
2. you will need to do some work so relevance quality is good, as honda and civic are not really synonyms. So you should at least have two fields, one with synonyms and one without and score the one without higher than the other.

Comment: Are there other ways to do it?

Comment: @user432024 For any suggestion about "other ways", you'd have to give examples of why using synonyms wouldn't work - usually you'd have classification of vehicles already (i.e. honda / civic) in a classifieds context.